# Horizontal Icons In Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am trying to display three social media icons horizontally in my navigation bar, however whatever I do, they seem to display below one another. To create my navigation bar I am using 'Off Canvas Menu Effects' to have it slide in and out (this will explain some of the strange css). I have only posted the html and css off the navigation below, I hope this is enough to help you help me lol.

```css
.menu, 
.icon-list {
 height: 100%;
}

.icon-list a img {
 max-width:100%;
 margin-left: -5px;
}

.icon-list {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

.icon-list a {
 display: block;
 /*padding: 0.8em;*/
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,500px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,500px,0);
}

.icon-list,
.icon-list a {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0s 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0s 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1000px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,1000px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1500px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,1500px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,2000px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,2000px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(5) {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,2500px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,2500px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(6) {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,3000px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,3000px,0);
}

.icon-list a span {
 font-weight: 700;
}

.icons{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
}

.facebook {
 
}

.twitter{
 
}

.linkedin{

}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
     <div class="icon-list">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo"></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-star-o"></i><span>HOME</span></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i><span>ABOUT</span></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope-o"></i><span>PRODUCTS</span></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment-o"></i><span>SALES & MOTIVATION</span></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i><span>CONTACT</span></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper-o"></i><span>CONNECT</span></a>
       <div class="icons"> 
        <a href="facebook.com"><img src="facebook.jpg" alt="facebook" class="facebook">
        <a href="twitter.com"><img src="twitter.jpg" alt="twitter" class="twitter"></a>
        <a href="linkedin.com"><img src="linkedin.jpg" alt="linkedin" class="linkedin"></a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: try `display: block` instead `display: inline-block` in `.icons` class

Comment: didn't work, already tried :(

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not 100% sure what you're expecting as the end result, but I think this will help.

Firstly, `display: block` is exactly what makes things stack on top of each other, so you definitely don't want that. Change that in your `.icon-list a` selector to `display: inline-block`.

Secondly you're forcing the width of your `icons` container to be smaller than the total width of the social icons together. Remove the width on `.icons`.

Lastly you can't have `display: inline-block` and `float: left` in the same rule, so choose one. In the codepen I've made for you, I've chosen `inline-block` but `float: left` works the same. You're already using FontAwesome so I changed your images to brand icons provided by the font set.

[here's a codepen with the code in it](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/WvWWmz/). Let me know if you need further help with your specific problem.

Comment: I see what you mean but the thing is the navigation bar is vertical so all the text will be displayed in a vertical list. However, I want to icons to display horizontally like this [IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/2dr6lx5.png[/IMG]

Comment: Ok so you should just use `display: block` for the vertical stuff `display: inline-block` for the horizontal stuff.

Comment: That's how the original code was and it didn't work :(

Comment: In your original code the `.icons` class has a rule of `width: 40px`. How can you expect to fit icons horizontally in a container that doesn't have space for them? Just remove the `width` property from that class or make it `width: 100%`

Comment: You probably meant `.icons a { width: 40px, etc }`, that would select the actual icons not their container.

Comment: just tried that, nothing changed... I removed the width and height settings for the .icons and set it to inline-block,

Comment: I would be willing to help you out further if you could make a codepen or fiddle of your problem

Answer (score 1):

i got it to work after alot of effort :) There were two things causing the trouble `display:block` in the `icons` class and `max-width:100%` in the `icon-list a img` selector. Here is the updated code:

```
    .menu, 
.icon-list {
    height: 100%;
}
.icon-list a img {
    max-width:30%;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
.icon-list {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,100px,0);
}
.icon-list a {
    /*padding: 0.8em;*/
    display: inline;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,500px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,500px,0);
}
.icon-list,
.icon-list a {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0s 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0s 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}
.icon-list a:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1000px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,1000px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1500px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,1500px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,2000px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,2000px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,2500px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,2500px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,3000px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,3000px,0);
}

.icon-list a span {
    font-weight: 700;
}
.icons{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display:inline;
    float: left;
}
.facebook {
}

.twitter{
}

.linkedin{
}

<nav class="menu">
                    <div class="icon-list">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo"></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-star-o"></i><span>HOME</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i><span>ABOUT</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope-o"></i><span>PRODUCTS</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment-o"></i><span>SALES & MOTIVATION</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i><span>CONTACT</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper-o"></i><span>CONNECT</span></a>
                            <div class="icons"> 
                                <a href="facebook.com"><img src="facebook.jpg" alt="facebook" class="facebook" /></a>
                                <a href="twitter.com"><img src="twitter.jpg" alt="twitter" class="twitter"></a>
                                <a href="linkedin.com"><img src="linkedin.jpg" alt="linkedin" class="linkedin"></a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for putting in so much effort!! Right now the icons are displaying horizontally but everything else is as well
http://tinypic.com/r/2ptosk2/8
but i want it to look like this 
http://tinypic.com/r/2dr6lx5/8

Comment: i can do this but for that i need to change your html a bit :)

Comment: Go for it hahahah Im on the verge of giving up now lol. The navigation bar doesnt seem to work when the page scrolls as well.. sigh this is such a damn hassle -.-

Comment: giving up should never be an option i believe especially in programming :p